# Order in a line command in G-code

Tags: g-code, 3d-printerworks

I've started learning G-code for 3D printing and I'm quite confused.

I'm using an Ultimaker S5 printer and the firmware is : 5.5.12 - 20200226-UltiBot

1. Is there a difference between `G1 F1200 X188 Y92 E0.01` and `G1 X188 Y92 F1200 E0.01`?
2. Most of my code looks like: `G1 X[coordinate] Y[coordinate] E[num]` without Z!
   How is this possible?! My model is a 3D-model so how come the letter Z appears about 5 times in tens of papers?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used every flavor of gcode or firmware, but I've never seen the parameter order be important, provided that:

1. The **G** or **M** code was the initial entry; and
2. Each parameter was clearly listed with one or more spaces between parameters; and
3. No spaces were in between the parameter letter and the value.

We use a custom version of Repetier firmware to run 3D printers and Fadal CNC machines, and in every use  `G1 F1200 X188 Y92 E0.01` would be evaluated and executed completely identically to `G1 X188 Y92 F1200 E0.01`

Nearly all gocde variable values are persistent, so if Z remains unchanged because it is only specified once per layer, or if Z remains unchanged because it is explicitly specified (with the same value) on every line, there should be no difference in the behavior of the printer.

Comment: To expand a little on @Davo's answer. Any parameter that is omitted but required for movement is assumed by the g-code interpreter to have the same value in the state machine as when it was last provided. This is true for F, X, Y and Z. If the op wants to go hardcore though: https://www.nist.gov/publications/nist-rs274ngc-interpreter-version-3

Comment: @user77232 And E! (then it will be a move without extrusion) See [the G0-G1 sources](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/gcode/motion/G0_G1.cpp). A parser is used to parse the arguments of a command, the `seen` method is used to determine if a parameter is specified in the G-code command (whatever the position is), if not, the already set one from previous commands is used.